# getAttribute() method in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

How to retrieve the text given in any field using javascript in C#?

```
sumry.innerHTML += "<li>" + f.getAttribute("Text") + "</li>" + "<br/>";
                        f.style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
                        f.focus();
```

Comment: defined "field". you mean the content of the tag or the content of the attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `.nodeValue`, possibly `.innerHTML`, possibly `.value` for a form field.

`.getAttribute()` will retrieve an attribute from a tag, such as `id` or `name`.  It won't get the content of the tag.

---

Your current code is expecting an element formed like this:

```
<some_element id='blah' text='hey hey hey' />`
```

Of course, `text` is not an attribute, so there's no return value.

Comment: Thanks,   but  i want to retrieve "Text" attribute of textbox?

Comment: For `<input>` and `<textarea>`, use `.value`.

Comment: @HiteshDhamat that would be `.value` as described in this answer. For example: `document.getElementById("myTextBox").value`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.. If i got it, you want to use data from code behind in your script. The easiest way is to create a hidden field, set its value on form load, and then read it using getElementById('myhidden').value.

Best regards.